# Meteor 0.9.0.1: simple-schema not found after installing CollectionFS and cfs:filesystem

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to get install [CollectionFS](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS) and  [cfs:filesystem](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-cfs-filesystem) on my project as I want to upload files.  I've added collectionfs and cfs-filesystem to my smart.json file and did a mrt update.  The packages appeared to install ok but when I tried to run my app I got an error "Error: unknown package: simple-schema".  This package I know works as it was working perfectly well before I tried installing these two new packages.

I've checked my packages folder and simple-schema is definitely there.

Anyone got any idea how to get simple-schema working again?

smart.json:

```
{
  "packages": {
  "collectionfs": {},
  "cfs-filesystem": {},
  "simple-schema": {},
  "collection2": {},
  "autoform": {},
  "iron-router": "0.8.2",
  "less-bootstrap-3": {},
  "font-awesome-4-less": {},
  "npm": {},
  "fs": {},
  "roles": {},
  "accounts-ui-bootstrap-3": {},
  "accounts-admin-ui-bootstrap-3": {}
  }
}
```

Output from the terminal:

```
$ mrt update
✓ data-man
branch: https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-data-man.git#master
✓ collectionfs
tag: https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS.git#v0.4.9
✓ cfs-filesystem
tag: https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-cfs-filesystem.git#v0.0.28
✓ simple-schema
tag: https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema.git#v1.0.2
✓ collection2
tag: https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2.git#v0.4.6
✓ autoform
tag: https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform.git#v1.0.0
✓ iron-router
tag: https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router.git#v0.8.2
✓ less-bootstrap-3
tag: https://github.com/DerMambo/less-bootstrap-3.git#v0.0.2
✓ font-awesome-4-less
tag: https://github.com/svub/fontawesome4-less.git#v4.4.0
✓ npm
tag: https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-npm.git#v0.2.6
✓ fs
tag: https://github.com/peerlibrary/meteor-fs.git#v0.1.4
✓ roles
tag: https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles.git#v1.2.11
✓ accounts-ui-bootstrap-3
tag: https://github.com/mangasocial/meteor-accounts-ui-bootstrap-3.git#v0.3.5
✓ accounts-admin-ui-bootstrap-3
tag: https://github.com/hharnisc/meteor-accounts-admin-ui-bootstrap-3.git#v0.2.6
✓ cfs-base-package
tag: https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-cfs-base-package.git#v0.0.25
✓ cfs-file
tag: https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-cfs-file.git#v0.1.13
✓ cfs-collection
tag: https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-cfs-collection.git#v0.4.13
✓ cfs-collection-filters
tag: https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-cfs-collection-filters.git#v0.1.3
✓ cfs-access-point
tag: https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-cfs-access-point.git#v0.0.39
✓ cfs-worker
tag: https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-cfs-worker.git#v0.0.20
✓ cfs-upload-http
tag: https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-cfs-upload-http.git#v0.0.15
✓ cfs-storage-adapter
tag: https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-cfs-storage-adapter.git#v0.0.31
✓ moment
tag: https://github.com/acreeger/meteor-moment.git#v2.8.1
✓ iron-layout
tag: https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-layout.git#v0.2.0
✓ assert
tag: https://github.com/peerlibrary/meteor-assert.git#v0.2.4
✓ blocking
tag: https://github.com/peerlibrary/meteor-blocking.git#v0.4.1
✓ cfs-filesaver
tag: https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-cfs-filesaver.git#v0.0.4
✓ http-methods
tag: https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-http-methods.git#v0.0.23
✓ numeral
tag: https://github.com/vsivsi/meteor-numeral.git#v1.5.3
✓ emitter
tag: https://github.com/Meteor-Reaction/meteor-emitter.git#v0.1.0
✓ cfs-upload-ddp
tag: https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-cfs-upload-ddp.git#v0.0.12
✓ cfs-tempstore
tag: https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-cfs-tempstore.git#v0.0.29
✓ http-publish
tag: https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-http-publish.git#v0.0.10
✓ cfs-gridfs
tag: https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-cfs-gridfs.git#v0.0.24
✓ power-queue
tag: https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-power-queue.git#v0.9.9
✓ reactive-list
tag: https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-reactive-list.git#v0.0.7
✓ cfs-graphicsmagick
tag: https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-cfs-graphicsmagick.git#v0.0.15
✓ blaze-layout
tag: https://github.com/EventedMind/blaze-layout.git#v0.2.5
✓ iron-core
tag: https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-core.git#v0.2.0
✓ iron-dynamic-template
tag: https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-dynamic-template.git#v0.2.1
✓ cfs-ejson-file
tag: https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-cfs-ejson-file.git#v0.0.8
✓ reactive-property
tag: https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-reactive-property.git#v0.0.1
✓ micro-queue
tag: https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-micro-queue.git#v0.0.3

Done installing smart packages
me@ubuntu:~/myapp$ meteor
Figuring out the best package versions to use. This may take a moment.
Refreshing package metadata. This may take a moment.
Could not resolve the specified constraints for this project:
Error: unknown package: simple-schema
me@ubuntu:~/myapp$
```

Answer (score 0):

In Meteor 0.9, you shouldn't be using smart.json anymore.

Instead, Meteor introduced its own packaging system and you can now install packages via

```
meteor add
```

Many atmosphere packages have updated names, you can find them on [atmospherejs.com](http://atmospherejs.com)

[Checkout this excellent upgrade guide](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/updating-to-090/)